# Loading IIS website in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am not sure if there's a way to load an IIS website into Eclipse. Similar to the way we can load in Visual Studio through File > Open Website

Thanks

Comment: You can create a new project based off of the files from anywhere, including a .NET website, but you probably will not get much help from Eclipse in code completion, or really doing anything nice like Visual Studio.  If it is plain HTML, CSS, Javascript, there are plugins that work very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: with an open source web application server such as Tomcat you can run it inside Eclipse.  You can set breakpoints, check variable values at runtime, etc.  However, Microsoft is about as far from open source as you can get; if you want to run IIS through a debugger, you're going to have to use Visual Studio or some similar MS-only tool, because that's how MS designs things.

Of course, as Kekoa pointed out, you can always load the individual files in Eclipse, but then you're just using it as a glorified text editor; to get the full power of all of it's "IDE" capabilities, you really need to use a non-MS (and non-proprietary in general) stack.